# How can I control the select2 select box from an external list box?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I am working with the `select2` multiple select box. I want to display the result of my selection in an external list. From this list I also want to be able to remove the items again. It is working more or less but is getting kind of buggy after removing some items from the external list and insert it again via the select box. I visualized everything here to illustrate my problem :

```js
$(function () {
  //Initialize Select2 Elements
  $(".select2").select2();
});

$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".select2").on("change", function () {
    $(".select2-selection__rendered li").each(function () {
      var title = $(this).attr('title');
      if (typeof title !== typeof undefined && title !== false) {
        var animal = title.replace(/ /g, "");
        $('#' + animal).show();
      }
    });
  });


  $(".remove").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".animals").hide();
    var className = $($(this).closest("li")).attr('id');
    $(".select2-selection__rendered li[title='" + className + "']").remove();
  });

});
```

```css
.remove{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class=" form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="+ select" style="width: 100%;">
    <option>Cat</option>
    <option>Dog</option>
    <option>Bird</option>
  </select>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="animals" id="Cat" style="display:none">Cat <a class="remove">x</a></li>
  <li class="animals" id="Dog" style="display:none">Dog <a class="remove">x</a></li>
  <li class="animals" id="Bird" style="display:none">Bird <a class="remove">x</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the way you remove the items from your `select2`, I suggest to give your `option`'s a value then when you click on the li get the title and remove the matched option that have `value=title` from the list of selected values and reassign the new array to your select : :

```
var new_values = $(".select2").val().filter(item => item !== className);
$(".select2").val(new_values).change();
```

**NOTE :** you don't need two `ready` functions just one enough.

Hope this helps.

**Example using `filter()` method :**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".select2").select2();

  $(".select2").on("change", function () {
    $(".select2-selection__rendered li").each(function () {
      var title = $(this).attr('title');
      
      if (typeof title !== typeof undefined && title !== false) {
        var animal = title.replace(/ /g, "");
        $('#' + animal).show();
      }
    });
  });


  $(".remove").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".animals").hide();
    
    var className = $($(this).closest("li")).attr('id');
    var new_values = $(".select2").val().filter(item => item !== className);
    
    $(".select2").val(new_values).change();
  });

});
```

```css
.remove{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class=" form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="+ select" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value='Cat'>Cat</option>
    <option value='Dog'>Dog</option>
    <option value='Bird'>Bird</option>
  </select>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="animals" id="Cat" style="display:none">Cat <a class="remove">x</a></li>
  <li class="animals" id="Dog" style="display:none">Dog <a class="remove">x</a></li>
  <li class="animals" id="Bird" style="display:none">Bird <a class="remove">x</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Example using `$.each()` method :**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".select2").select2();

  $(".select2").on("change", function () {
    $(".select2-selection__rendered li").each(function () {
      var title = $(this).attr('title');

      if (typeof title !== typeof undefined && title !== false) {
        var animal = title.replace(/ /g, "");
        $('#' + animal).show();
      }
    });
  });


  $(".remove").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".animals").hide();

    var className = $($(this).closest("li")).attr('id');

    var new_values = [];

    $.each($(".select2").val(),function(index, item){
      if( item !== className )
        new_values.push(item);
    })

    $(".select2").val(new_values).change();
  });

});
```

```css
.remove{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class=" form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="+ select" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value='Cat'>Cat</option>
    <option value='Dog'>Dog</option>
    <option value='Bird'>Bird</option>
  </select>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="animals" id="Cat" style="display:none">Cat <a class="remove">x</a></li>
  <li class="animals" id="Dog" style="display:none">Dog <a class="remove">x</a></li>
  <li class="animals" id="Bird" style="display:none">Bird <a class="remove">x</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have a conflict in this line  `var new_values = $(".select2").val().filter(item => item !== className);` Do you have an idea why?

Comment: The conflict came up today! Yesterday everything worked

Comment: HAve you added more elements with class `select2` to your document?

Comment: No I haven't but as you see, even your preview here is not working anymore, see?

Comment: No my preview works just fine. check in another browser.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In Chrome it is working, but not in Safari

Comment: Do you know what could cause the problem in Safari?

Comment: Not sure it may the `filter()` function, i'll try to change it by another method.

Comment: Check the new fiddle using `each()` please.